# Columns not showing under Structure tab in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, structure

I have set up phpmyadmin for the first time ever and everything seems to be working fine except that under the Structure tab none of the columns are showing up. This is proving to be problematic as I wish to drop/change some of my columns. I have not been able to find any information on why this is occuring.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and restarting Mysql Server helped.

I have no idea what the actual problem was...

-FT

Comment: This worked for me as well... problem was `/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/tmp/ibcXVrTD' (Errcode: 2)`

Comment: any idea how restarting could be done on a godaddy shared server?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The reason was in changed write permissions on `/tmp` directory.

Where I ran `Describe TABLENAME;` command in **phpmyadmin** SQL tab it failed with error message that it was unable to write into `/tmp` directory.

So I have changed permissions on `/tmp` through `chmod` and the issue disappeared.

Comment: My issue was similar. It was looking for /var/mysqltmp which didn't exist. symlinking it to /tmp solved it for me

Comment: Great! Thank you for your advice

chmod 777 /tmp
 
but just worry is it ok to give 777 permission (I tried 755 but still having problem)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, when the type column contained ű or ő character. For example enum('műszaki','stb'). Other characters like áíóé does not make this error. And as I seen, everything was set up as UTF-8. So the solution for me was:

In phpMyAdmin verison 4.0.4 I changed Util.class.php on line 3018.

```
//$displayed_type .= substr($printtype, 0, $GLOBALS['cfg']['LimitChars']);
$displayed_type .= mb_substr($printtype, 0, $GLOBALS['cfg']['LimitChars']);
```

In an older version of phpMyAdmin I changed tbl_structure.php line 276.

```
//$type = '<abbr title="' . $type . '">' . substr($type, 0, $GLOBALS['cfg']['LimitChars']) . '</abbr>';
$type = '<abbr title="' . $type . '">' . mb_substr($type, 0, $GLOBALS['cfg']['LimitChars']) . '</abbr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct permission of /tmp folder:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```